# Python Error 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run the following piece of code but I always get that error,Python Error 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, any help?

```
  sent_maxlen= None


def get_fixed_size(sents):
        """
        Partition sents into lists of sent_maxlen elements
        (execept the last in each sentence, which might be shorter)
        """
        return [sent[s_ind : s_ind + sent_maxlen]
                for sent in sents
                for s_ind in range(0, len(sent), sent_maxlen)]
```

Comment: Why would `sent_maxlen` _not_ be `None`?

Comment: By the way "you are not equals to None, you are None", which means you should test `None` with `is None` of `is not None`

Comment: yea I figured that just forgot to edit it in the code, thanks though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are some typos in your code. There is both `sent_maxlex`, and `sent_maxlen`.

In the code you posted, `sent_maxlen` (assuming the above typo was unintentional), is initialised to be `None`. This variable is used as the third argument in the `range()` function, which is the 'step' or the 'stride' of the iterator, that is, how much the iterator is incremented by each iteration (so it makes sense it cannot be non-numeric, and should have an absolute value greater than zero if we want the loop to ever finish).

From the function description it looks like the function is meant to turn a list of words into a list of lists of words, which each sublist having `sent_maxlen` elements (apart from the last sublist). As the user of the code, can you correctly initialise the `sent_maxlen` to what length you want 
these sublists to be?

Comment: Yes I did that as a temporary solution, thank you for your explanation.